# Programming apps for windows hand-held terminal device [Motorola MC67]

Tags: c#, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6, handhelddevice

I have a motorola mc67 which runs with windows CE and i need to create a program for this device. I am using visual studio 2015 CE right now and i don't even know where to start a project.

Tried to create a web application instead but device doesn't really like javascript or jquery.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a question that you can ask on StackOverflow. What are you expecting? Step by step directions for building a Windows CE application?

Answer (score 2):

The MC67 is avilable as MC67NA and MC67ND. The NA is running Android and the ND runs Windows Mobile 6.5 (also called Windows Embedded Hadheld 6.5), based on Windows CE 5.
The latest Visual Sudio supporting Windows CE 5 and Windows Mobile 6.5 SDKs is Visual Studio 2008 (no Express Version)!

If you are thinking about a web based application you have to program against the restricted html/javascript support of Internet Explorer Mobile 6.1 comming with the OS. Or you switch your web based stuff to Motorola's RhoMobile HTML5 suite of clients, servers and plugins.

See also https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Mobile+Computers/Handheld+Computers/MC67NA_US-EN

and

http://rhomobile.com/